# Why does the result of #pragma omp parallel look like this

Tags: c, openmp

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a=0, b=0;
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(16)
        {
            // #pragma omp single
            a++;
            // #pragma omp critical
            b++;
        }
        printf("single: %d -- critical: %d\n", a, b);
    }
```

Why is my output single: `5 -- critical: 5` here?
And why is it output single: `3 -- critical: 3` when `num_threads(4)`?

I should not code anything like this, right? If the threads are confused here (I guess), why the result is consistent?

Comment: Besides the race condition @Laci pointed out, note that the value of `a` and `b` are certainly stored on the same cache line and this cause them to be more likely to be the same due to the way processors works (at least on x86-64 Intel processor and certainly on AMD too). Hyper-threading can have a strong impact on this too. On my machine I get almost always 16 but sometimes 15. This is obviously something you should not rely on and very platform dependent.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for your explaination!

Answer (score 3):

You have race conditions, therefore the values of `a` and `b` are undefined. To correct it you can

a) use reduction (it is the best solution):

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(16) reduction(+:a,b)
```

b) use atomic operations (generally it is less efficient):

```
#pragma omp atomic 
   a++;
#pragma omp atomic
   b++;
```

c) use critical section (i.e. locks, which is the worst solution):

```
#pargma omp critical
{
   a++;
   b++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just pure luck, helped by inherent timing of the operation. Since this is the first parallel section in your program, threads are built instead of reused. That occupies the main thread for a while and results in threads starting sequentially. Therefore the chance of overlapping operations is lower. Try adding a `#pragma omp barrier` in between to increase the chance of race conditions becoming apparent.